# Pre-filled input text (watermark) - how to prevent value from being submitted via jQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, input, watermark

I am using the [jQuery Example plugin](https://github.com/mudge/jquery_example) to pre-fill text input fields of a form.

It works nicely, by clearing the input on focus and whatever you type in there is preserved on blur.

The documentation for the plugin says that it will prevent submitting the pre-fill text at submission. But there is no comment on what happens when submitting via Ajax.

When I submit my form (via Ajax), the pre-fill text is actually sent to the server.

I wonder if anyone can help with ideas on how to empty `value` on ajax if the input field is empty or contains the pre-fill text.

Thanks for helping.

This is the form

```
<form action="http://example.com/1" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="posts_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="posts_text" value="" id="posts_text" class="example">

</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('#posts_text').example('What\'s on your mind?');

function submitPost() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat/posts_submit/' + <?php echo $page_id; ?>,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#posts_form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function(){
              $('#loading').show();
            },          
        success: function(html) {
            $('#posts_insert').replaceWith(html);
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
}

$('.share_js').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    submitPost();
    return false; // dont move to top
});
```

Comment: You will have to do validation of the input content. i.e. if(input1.value === 'example text'){Throw error...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if it says "What's on your mind?" and ask the user to enter something with this code:

```
function submitPost(){
    if($("#posts_text").val() == "What's on your mind?"){
        alert("Please enter what's on your mind...");
    }else{
        // Continue on submitting via Ajax
    }
}
```

Ad@m

Comment: thanks @adam -- your code works nicely, i think i may use it but for now i am trying [jquery watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) as an alternative -- it seems to prevent submission of values without a hitch